# Get gps provider setting mode

Tags: codenameone

How can I get the gps location method?

The image shows gps only is selected in the location setting. Is there any way I can get this setting in cn1?

[image]

Code in cn1:

```
Location locationn = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but `isGPSEnabled()` is available in `LocationManager`. Notice it might throw a runtime exception on unsupported platforms.

You can use native interfaces if it's exposed to Android native but since it's Android specific it's not really a part of the API.

Notice the `Location` class provides `getAccuracy()` if that helps.

Comment: no isGpsEnabled only tells if gps is on or off. In the above img, if the gps only is selected, the possiblity of null is very high as compared to when "gps, wifi and mobile network" is selected. So I need to know which one is selected in the setting. getAccuracy() is of no use if null or zero loction value is received.

Comment: I think the only right thing to do is handle `null` correctly and possibly prompt the user. I think some apps send you directly to this activity if it's off so you might be able to just fire an intent with `Display.execute()`.

Comment: I've solved it using native interface for this. But theres a minor glich in isGpsEnabled method. Though location is on (but "battery saving mode" or "wifi,bluetooth or cellular networks mode" mode is selected in location setting), it gives false.

Comment: Can you file an issue on that? I doubt we'll have time to handle it for 4.0 as we're in the final stretch.